# I can't boot into Ubuntu _ Cannot find GRLDR in all devices

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7. It was working fine, but now when I try to boot with Ubuntu after GRUB boot menu I get this.

[image]

```
Try (hd0,0): NTFS5: No wubildr
Try (hd0,1): Extended:
Try (hd0,2): Invalid or null
Try (hd0,3): Invalid or null
Try (hd0,4): NTFS5: No wubildr
Try (hd0,5): Extended:
Try (hd0,5): NTFS5: No wubildr
Try (hd0,6): Extended:
Try (hd0,6): FAT32: No WUBILDR
Try (fd0): Invalid or null
Error: Cannot find GRLDR in all devices. Press ctrl+alt+del to restart.
```

And when I press ctrl+alt+del it restarts the computer and if I chose to boot with Ubuntu the same thing happens again, but Windows works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search for the WUBILDR.* files on your Windows 7.

They were located on the Ubuntu folder.

Then copy -not move- the 3 files directly to c:/

and it will work!!

Comment: this solution did not work in my case .. :( can u guys suggest any other solution..

Answer (score 3):

Exactly. . . wubildr and wubildr.mbr are the files that get created on your C:/ drive when you install ubuntu using wubi.

If we tend to remove any of these files there may be an error when booting into windows which says may resemble this:

Try (hd0,0) : NTFS5: No wubildr

Try (hd0,1) : Extended :

Try (hd0,2): Invalid or null

Try (hd0,3): Invalid or null

Try (hd0,4) : NTFS5: No wubildr

Try (hd0,5) : Extended :

Try (hd0,5) : NTFS5: No wubildr

Try (hd0,6) : Extended :

Try (hd0,5) : FAT32: No WUBILDR

Try (fd0) : Invalid or null

Error: Cannot find GRLDR in all devices. Press ctrl+alt+del to reastart...

Solution. . .Log into Windows. You might have installed Ubuntu using Wubi on either C:/ drive or any other drive. Go to "ubuntu" folder in the location where ubuntu is installed. Copy wubildr and wubildr.mbr from this location and paste it in C:/ (not inside any folder).

Now reboot. . .and try booting into Ubuntu. . I'm sure. . it works. . .

Answer (score 1):

The method to solve the problem is:

1. Log on to your Windows operating system.
2. Click on Windows C Drive and you can see two files named `wubildr` and `wubildr.mbr`. These two files have to be replaced by new ones.
3. Open the drive for Linux in Windows. Open the folder named Ubuntu and look out for `wubildr` and `wubildr.mbr`.
4. Right click on these files separately and click Properties. In the 'Previous Versions' tab, select a  previous version and click 'open'. Then copy (Replace) these files to your C drive.

**Courtesy:** http://arjunpe.blogspot.in/2012/07/cannot-find-grldr-in-all-devices-press.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution given in the other answers did not work for me.

What **did** work was copying `wubildr` and `wubildr.mbr` to a flash drive and booting Ubuntu from there.